# MySQL innodb: Safe to rely on default order when using LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I use an innodb table to store contact information. 
I display data paginated. The query for the first page looks like this:

```
SELECT name, email FROM contacts WHERE userid = 1 LIMIT 0,50
```

The column email in compound with userid is the primary key, so the result is sorted by it by default. 
The query for the second page looks like this;

```
SELECT name, email FROM contacts WHERE userid = 1 LIMIT 50,50
```

Now my question: Is it safe to rely on the default sorting order of innodb (I know I could simply add `ORDER BY email` To make sure)?
In other words, is it possible that the same contacts might be shown on page one and on page two? What would that depend on?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not "safe" to rely on any "default ordering" from InnoDB.

But this really depends on how you define "safe". Absent an `ORDER BY` clause, MySQL does *not*  guarantee that rows will be returned in any particular order. (We may observe repeatable behavior that appears to be reliable, but this is *not* a guarantee. So, I don't consider it to be safe.

To put that another way, the second query (with the LIMIT 50,50) could return the EXACT same set of rows as the first query (LIMIT 0,50) and be within the spec. (Obviously, for this to happen, there would need to be at least 100 rows that satisfy the query predicates.)

Consider what happens when the DBA upgrades MySQL, or the InnoDB plugin, and the behavior is not the same. Consider what happens if the DBA changes the storage engine from InnoDB to some other newer, faster storage engine. Consider what happens if the DBA changes the primary key from one candidate key to another candidate key.

If you are relying on rows being returned in a particular order, it is "safe" to explicitly specify that in an `ORDER BY` clause. When it's explicitly specified, it's much more likely that the poor guy deciphering your code will recognize that your code is expecting rows to be returned in a particular order. Looking at the code, does he know that the referenced table is using the InnoDB storage engine, and that you are dependent on some implicitly assumed behavior?

--

Q: Is it possible that the same contacts might be shown on page one and on page two? What would that depend on?

A: Yes, It's possible. You're unlikely to see it happen without some change being made. Consider what happens if a DELETE operation is performed (say by some other session) after your first query, and before your second query. Your query pattern has the potential to return the same rows. There's also a potential for skipping some rows, if rows are inserted.

There are improved "next page" query patterns. The one that I use is to use an `ORDER BY` a unique key, (or some set of non-unique columns, either includes or comprises a unique key. Save the all of the values in the "ORDER BY" expressions from the last row of the previous query, and the "next page" query includes predicates (WHERE clause) that returns only rows that "follow" that last retrieved row.

**UPDATE**

Assuming `id` is primary key or unique key, for the first page:

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.email
     , c.id
  FROM contacts c 
 WHERE c.userid = 1
 ORDER BY c.id
 LIMIT 50
```

Save the value of the `id` column from the last retrieved row, and have that passed back on the "next page" request. For next page query,

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.email
     , c.id
  FROM contacts c 
 WHERE c.userid = 1
   AND c.id > :last_retrieved_value
 ORDER BY c.id
 LIMIT 50
```

The query predicates are only a little more complex if you are ordering by something that isn't unique. For example, if you order by `name`, then by `id`

First page query is much the same:

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.email
     , c.id
  FROM contacts c 
 WHERE c.userid = 1
 ORDER
    BY c.name
     , c.id
 LIMIT 50
```

Save the values from `name` and `id` of last fetched row. Next page query uses those values:

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.email
     , c.id
  FROM contacts c 
 WHERE c.userid = 1
   AND c.name >= :last_fetched_name
   AND NOT ( c.name = :last_fetched_name AND c.id <= :last_fetched_id )
 ORDER
    BY c.name
     , c.id
 LIMIT 50
```

If you want to get even fancier, you could enhance that to check whether you fetched the last row or not. Change the query to `LIMIT 51`, use only the first 50 rows (save the values from that 50th row), and check whether you got a 51st row. If you didn't get a row, then you're at the end of the rows, and there's no need to enabled a "next page" button.

---

**EDIT**

This line in the query above:

```
   AND NOT ( c.name = :last_fetched_name AND c.id <= :last_fetched_id )
```

could be replaced with equivalent:

```
   AND ( c.name > :last_fetched_name  OR  c.id > :last_fetched_id )
```

Answer (score 1):

(I assume userid is not the PK otherwise the query doesn't make sense).

No, it's not safe. InnoDB returns rows in order of index it's reading from.
Say, you have indexes `idx_a (userid, field_a)` and `idx_b (userid, field_b)`. On some reason the optimizer decides to use `idx_a` for the first query and `idx_b` for the second. Obviously you'll get different record sets.

Even if there is an index `idx (userid)` MySQL may decide to read from PRIMARY (when userid=1 is the most of the table's records)